# Enable iterative calculation in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

Hi is it possible when using phpexcel to have iterative calculation enabled as to allow circular references when the user opens the created file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHPExcel supports circular references in formulae; but only if you configure it to do so.... in the same way that MS Excel default behaviour is to throw an exception to the GUI unless you specifically enable cyclic calculation for n iterations, that's the same default behaviour in PHPExcel.

However, just as you can set cyclic calculation for n iterations in MS Exce, you can do the same in PHPExcel using:

```
PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)
    ->cyclicFormulaCount = 100;
```

The current develop branch on github even has `13calculationCyclicFormulae.php` in the `Examples` folder demonstrating this.